# Custom constraint in OpenAPI Specification 3.0.0 (java)

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi

In the project we use open api 3.0. I need to write a custom validator for JsonNullable value...
specification:

```
Characteristic:
      type: object
      required:
        - name
        - value
      description: Describes a given characteristic of an object or entity through a
        name/value pair.
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          description: Unique identifier of characteristic
        name:
          type: string
          description: Name of the characteristic
        valueType:
          type: string
          description: Data type of the value of the characteristic
        value:
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/Any"
          x-constraints: "@CustomNotNull"
```

anotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {CustomCharacteristicValidator.class})
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomNotNull {
    String message() default "Value must not be null.";
    boolean required() default true;
}
```

validator:

```
  @Component
public class CustomCharacteristicValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CustomNotNull, JsonNullable<Object>> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(JsonNullable<Object> value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
//        if (Objects.nonNull(value.get())) {
//            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
//            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("value can't be empty").addConstraintViolation();
//            return false;
//        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

used the following resources:

1. [How to inject custom spring validation inside swagger codegen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727892/how-to-inject-custom-spring-validation-inside-swagger-codegen)
2. https://bartko-mat.medium.com/openapi-generator-to-spring-boot-with-custom-java-validations-623381df9215
3. [How to use custom validators in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768778/how-to-use-custom-validators-in-spring)

**Problem:** The required annotation is generated for all data types except $ref: "#/components/schemas/Any"

```
  /**
   * Get value
   * @return value
  */
  @NotNull 
**//should be here**
  @Schema(name = "value", required = true)
  public JsonNullable<Object> getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

Maybe someone came across? Are there any solutions to this problem at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [Swagger schema properties ignored when using $ref - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33629750/113116)

Comment: very similar to the truth.. I'll check...